# Требования для js-разработчика

Tags: javascript

Сейчас работаю обычным веб-разработчиком, с js сталкиваюсь не так уж часто,  но приходя домой, читаю книги и смотрю курсы по этому языку. Через какое-то время планирую устроится js разработчиком, и, собственно, возник вопрос - какие знания необходимы для этого?

На одном из сайтов нашёл вот такой список:

Отличное знание чистого JavaScript;
опыт использования HTML5/CSS3;
понимание MVVM, опыт работы с KnockoutJS || BackboneJS || AngularJS;
кроссбраузерная верстка;
опыт работы с LESS или SASS;
знакомство с Lo-Dash, RequireJS, Kendo Web UI;
навыки работы с GIT.
Будет плюсом:
опыт работы с MongoDB;
опыт работы с *nix системами;
опыт работы с Node.js;
понимание принципов SPA и изоморфных web-приложений.

Этот список полон или его нужно чем-то дополнить?

Answer (score 2):

Я бы предложил выучить чистый js, jQuery, ознакомиться с ExtJs, bootstrap. Для клиентской части это уже очень неплохо. Чаще всего требуется именно jQuery.

Для проверки знаний и повышения ЧСВ пишите так, чтобы приложение проходило jsLint/Hint тесты.

Answer (score 2):

Для JS разработчика главное знать:

1. Чистый JavaScript: всякие ооп, замыкания, паттерны.
2. Языки HTML и CSS и как они отображаются в DOM дерево, полезно почитать стандарты и отличия для разных браузеров.
3. Ознакомиться с парой библиотек: jquery, extjs, Yahoo YUI Library.
4. Понимать, как строить AJAX приложения.
5. Знать, как построить (где заимствовать) самые базовые элементы интерфейса: ползунки, всплывающие окна, проверки форм, многостраничные формы, просмотры изображений (карусели, слайдеры), etc.
6. Можно познакомится с  Node.js.

Все остальное - это специфические требования, и у каждой конторы они свои. Кто-то может требовать GIT, кто-то знание серверных языков, кто-то знание API соцсетей, а кому-то все это не нужно. Вариантов много. Умение работать с MongoDB и .nix - это вообще что-то экзотическое.

Хотя стоит учесть, что на разработчика JavaScript часто накладывают еще и умение заниматься версткой страниц. Поэтому иметь хоть какой-то навык и в этом деле желательно.

Answer (score 2):

Можно разобрать все пункты по полочкам, будет понятней, для чего они нужны:

Отличное знание чистого JavaScript

Понятно, что для джс дева нужно хорошо знать яваскрипт, а правильнее сказать, хорошо понимать, как он работает. Если вы подзабыли какой-то метод, то не беда, главное знать, что есть такая возможность. На собеседовании вас будут спрашивать именно по чистому джс: работа с домом, события, замыкания, типы переменных (почему undefined == null вернет тру, а undefined === null фалсе), понимаете ли вы наследование и сколько способов знаете, спросят по мвц (тут как раз опыт с бекбоном поможет) и т.д.

Опыт использования HTML5/CSS3

Тут чистая верстка, должны быстро ориентироваться, как что сверстать и как быстро подфиксить съехавший лейбл или текст.

Понимание MVVM, опыт работы с KnockoutJS || BackboneJS || AngularJS;

Для построения сложных интерфейсов используют специальные фреймворки, объединяет их mvc. У вас есть коллекция моделей, в моделе есть какие-то данные, вьюшка, которая привязана к моделе. Простой пример: у вас есть вьюшка с формой для редактирования или добавления чего-либо. Если модель новая, то вы отрендерите вьюшку с активными инпутами, если модель уже сохранена на сервер, то вы отрендерите форму с инпутами только для чтения. Если вы открыли меню, то вы сохраните в моделе, что меню открыто и в следующий раз, когда вы захотите обновить данные во вьюшке, вы увидете, что меню было открыто и автоматом откроете его снова, как итог - нет никаких манипуляций с домом и проверок типа `this.ui.menu.is(":hidden")`.

кроссбраузерная верстка;

Тут тоже все понятно. Если надо будет сверстать новую страницу для сайта, конечно, все подразумевают, что она должна выглядеть одинакова во всех браузерах.

Опыт работы с LESS или SASS;

Большие проекты всегда используют лесс или саас, это удобно. Вы объявляете переменную @mainTextColor и потом используете ее везде, где надо в цсс.

знакомство с Lo-Dash, RequireJS, Kendo Web UI;

Тут, похоже, hr вписал страшные слова, которые он знал. Потому что реквайр джс и Кендо немного разные вещи. Если по-простому, Реквайр это загрузчик модулей и менеджер зависимостей. Для того чтобы можно было использовать одну форму в разных местах, ее делают модулем, и потом в модуль просто передают разные параметры, например, другой темплейт для формы с пятью полями, а не с двумя.

Кендо предлагает много готовых решений для интерфейса, надо просто погуглить.

Навыки работы с GIT.

Контроль версий должен знать любой человек, связанный с разработкой. Тут без вариантов.

Будет плюсом:
опыт работы с MongoDB;
опыт работы с *nix системами;

Что-то специфическое, например, проект использет монгу, и если у вас будут локально проблемы с поднятием базы, то будет плюсом, если вы сами с ними разберетесь. Но никто не запрещает обратиться за помощью.

опыт работы с Node.js;

Опыт работы с ним обязателен, хотя бы для того же цсс компилятора. Есть билд сервер, где установлены плагины для нода, которые из рабочих .less файлов сделают css файлы, которые минимизируют джс файлы, чтобы они меньше весили и т.д. Поэтому тоже надо, чтобы вы понимали как это работает. Как подготовить статику к продакшин виду.

Понимание принципов SPA и изоморфных web-приложений.

Тут надо погуглить.